# flutter: unexpected behaviour while using flutter hooks with provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using hooks to move my TextFormField logic to hooks class and to change the visibility of text I'm using provider but when tap on the button to change the visibility so I'm using focusNode to get initial focus to first field but when I tap it removes whole text from TextFormField and change focus to first field and if first field does have text then it doesn't remove it(I think it is rebuilding the UI)

my hooks file,

```
enum Index { email, password }

TextFormField useTextFormField(Index index) {
  return use(_CustomHook(index: index));
}

class _CustomHook extends Hook<TextFormField> {
  final Index index;

  _CustomHook({@required this.index});

  @override
  _CustomHookState createState() => _CustomHookState();
}

class _CustomHookState extends HookState<TextFormField, _CustomHook> {
  Index index;
  @override
  TextFormField build(BuildContext context) {
    final isVisible = Provider.of<VisibilityProvider>(context);
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'some help',
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              isVisible.changeVisibility();
            },
            icon: Icon(
                isVisible.visible ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
          )),
      validator: (text) {
        if (text.isEmpty) return 'enter something';

        return null;
      },
      obscureText: index == Index.email ? false : isVisible.visible,
    );
  }
}
```

provider file,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VisibilityProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

  bool _visible = true;

  bool get visible => _visible;
  void changeVisibility(){
    _visible = !_visible;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here?